# ros::package::getPath throws bad_alloc

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roscpp, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have quite a large ros repo and everything was working fine for a very long time. For some reason running it after Christmas I started seeing  the following:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc [kinematic_simulation-5] process has died [pid 42457, exit code -6, cmd /home/jj/ws/phd_ws/ws/devel/lib/perceptive_mpc/as_mpc_simulation_node /joint_states:=/as_control/joint_states __name:=kinematic_simulation __log:=/home/jj/.ros/log/59272bc6-6995-11ec-9acb-dc8b2894491d/kinematic_simulation-5.log]. log file: /home/jj/.ros/log/59272bc6-6995-11ec-9acb-dc8b2894491d/kinematic_simulation-5*.log`

I have isolated the error to the following line:

```
std::string packagePath = ros::package::getPath("perceptive_mpc");
```

I'm using melodic, docker. the perceptive_mpc package is built and sourced. The line itself is inside the package so its definitely seen. roslib is inside dependencies. I just have no clue at all. Only seen one issue similar online : https://answers.ros.org/question/296304/rospackagegetpath-seg-faults-in-kinetic/

Oh and most interesting of all: if I put an absolute path myself instead of using ros:package:getPath  -> everything runs fine.

Absolutely any help or advice appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393569/ros::package::getpath-throws-bad_alloc/) by [JuliusS](https://answers.ros.org/users/35565/juliuss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2021-12-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If anyone encounters this ->
Its likely todo with docker setup. In my case it was related to mounting /usr/share.
Once I stopped mounting this issue is resolved.

---

Originally posted by [JuliusS](https://answers.ros.org/users/35565/juliuss/) with karma: 21 on 2022-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-03**:
Thank you for sharing the answer